# How to get rid of @SuppressWarnings tag?

Tags: java, json, dictionary, casting, gson

I am trying to split a string and load the content into a Map like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Map<String, List<String>> holder = gson.fromJson(response.split("server=")[1],
        Map.class);
for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : holder.entrySet()) {
    for (String hosts : entry.getValue()) {
        serverList.add(hosts);
    }
}
```

My String is like this:

```
server={"ABC":["PQR"],"DEF":["HELLO"],"TYU":[]}
```

Now as you can see I am having `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` to remove the warning generate by Eclipse. This is a warning message I get:

```
Type safety: The expression of type Map needs unchecked conversion to conform to Map<String,List<String>>
```

Now my question is - Is there any other way to remove this warning message apart from adding that `SuppressWarnings` tag?

Comment: Nope, or the method must return a specific map with the correct template values, not a generic map. The reason behind this is that you know the map is actually unchecked so you cannot blame Java for being ""weird"
On a other note, why do you want it to be removed?

Comment: Let's get this straight, you want to suppress the @Suppress? Where will it all end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `TypeToken`

```
final Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, List<String>>>() {}.getType();
final Map<String, List<String>> holder = gson.fromJson(response.split("server=")[1], type);
```

Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30005110/how-does-gson-typetoken-work) to know how `TypeToken` works