# What does the {}.getType() syntax mean in Gson?

Tags: java, json, gson

In the Gson docs, I ran across this construct to use for converting a list of JSONified Spotify Artist objects back into the ArrayList of objects. I use this in the onRestoreInstanceState().

However, I have never seen the {} after a declaration. Can someone explain to me what it means? I know that getType() is a member class but why the {}?

```
 Type type = new TypeToken<List<Artist>>() {}.getType();
 mArtistsList = new Gson().fromJson(jsonSearchResults, type);
```

Comment: also check [this example from official docs](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Generic-Types)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`{}` means an [anonymous class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) that doesn't override any methods. Here's another anonymous class you've seen before:

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
   }
};
```

`.getType()` returns a [`java.lang.reflect.Type`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Type.html) which Gson uses to identify which `TypeAdapter` it's going to use to serialize and deserialize your `Object` / JSON `String`.

See [my answer here for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30007018/1768232) on how Gson uses this to infer the generic type parameter; the short version is that it needs to use an anonymous class or it wouldn't work.

Comment: Hey, thanks! The other question does not appear to me to be directly related, nor as succinct, as the one I have just asked. So, thanks.

Comment: @Kazinsky Also, yeah, the answer to your question is buried in that other, longer answer, but they're just barely enough different that I decided to answer this question anyway.