# Why protected constructor can be used to new instance outside of the package?

Tags: java, gson

From gson-2.8.6.jar

```
package com.google.gson.reflect;
...
public class TypeToken<T> {
  final Class<? super T> rawType;
  final Type type;
  final int hashCode;

  /**
   * Constructs a new type literal. Derives represented class from type
   * parameter.
   *
   * <p>Clients create an empty anonymous subclass. Doing so embeds the type
   * parameter in the anonymous class's type hierarchy so we can reconstitute it
   * at runtime despite erasure.
   */
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  protected TypeToken() {
    this.type = getSuperclassTypeParameter(getClass());
    this.rawType = (Class<? super T>) $Gson$Types.getRawType(type);
    this.hashCode = type.hashCode();
  }

  /**
   * Unsafe. Constructs a type literal manually.
   */
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  TypeToken(Type type) {
    this.type = $Gson$Types.canonicalize($Gson$Preconditions.checkNotNull(type));
    this.rawType = (Class<? super T>) $Gson$Types.getRawType(this.type);
    this.hashCode = this.type.hashCode();
  }
...
}
```

Outside of the package `com.google.gson.reflect`, why the `protected TypeToken()` constructor can be used to new an instance?
What's the grammar that `{}` appear after `new TypeToken<String>()`?

```
package com.dataservice.controller;

...
Type localVarReturnType = (new TypeToken<String>() {}).getType();
...
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31794926/what-does-the-gettype-syntax-mean-in-gson?noredirect=1&lq=1) answer your question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are seeing is the syntax for an anonymous class:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Essentially what happens is,

```
Type localVarReturnType = (new TypeToken<String>() {}).getType();
```

defines a new anonymous class which inherits from `TypeToken`. You can immediately derive this from the syntax `new` in combination with curly braces `{}`.

The reason why you are allowed to access the `protected` constructor, is because `protected` allows access for the package **OR** for inheriting classes. Since your anonymous class inherits from `TypeToken` access is then possible.