# Get a Class<T> literal or a Type

Tags: java, reflection, moshi

Is it possible to get something similar to `Class<List<Data>>.class`? I read you can't call `.class` because of how it works interanlly, so I was wondering if maybe using something similar to `new ArrayList<Data>().getClass()` might work? That one in particular doesn't work as the returned class is `Class<? extends List<Data>>` so I'm out of options, is it even possible?

**Context**: I'm trying to parse a `List<Data>` using [square/moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi) but the library seems to be on alpha so there is no documentation on it.

Comment: Generics use [Type Erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

What that basically means is that by the time your code is compiled all of the generics information is gone, and it is no longer available at run time.

So, there is no actual difference between a List<Data> and a List as far as runtime access (e.g. reflection) is concerned.

Comment: It seems that there is a method that accept a `Type` as parameter to create an adapter. You might want to provide it, the same way you can get a type with Gson 's `TypeToken` trick. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30005110/how-does-gson-typetoken-work

Answer (score 2):

There is no `Class` object that represents `List<Data>` because generic types are a compile-time feature only. It is possible to make a variable of static type `Class<List<Data>>` by doing this

```
Class<List<Data>> clazz = (Class<List<Data>>) (Object) List.class;
```

You get a compiler warning here. Really `clazz` is just `List.class` and the compiler warning is a hint that what you're doing is not a good idea.

There is no `Class` object representing `List<Data>` but there is a `Type` object.

Try this:

```
public class Main {

    List<String> list;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         // prints java.util.List<java.lang.String>
         System.out.println(Main.class.getField("list").getGenericType());   
    }
}
```

Comment: What if instead of `List<String>` it was `List<T>`?  I have to pass a `Type` object to a json parser library, and said type should be `List<Data>`, so that the library knows it should replace `T` for `Data`. Could it work?

Comment: I just tried it and it said `java.util.List<T>`. To be honest I'm getting dangerously close to the extent of my knowledge on this subject. I agree with Alexis C that you should look into `TypeToken`.