# How to get Generic function of TypeToken?

Tags: java

I have the following codes. I want to get a generic solution to get the `TypeToken` only passing the class reference.

```
Type application = new TypeToken<List<Application>>() {
}.getType();
Type bill = new TypeToken<List<Bill>>() {
}.getType();
Type payment = new TypeToken<List<Payment>>() {
}.getType();
```

I have tried to get the typeToken from an function only passing the class reference. What I have tried already.

```
private static <T> Type getType(Class<T>classType) {
    return new TypeToken<List<? extends T>>() {
    }.getType();
}
```

but when I call the method as `getType(Application.class)` this doesn't return me the List of Application TypeToken and something went wrong to use the Type. Please help me to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not possible due to type erasure. The reason `TypeToken` exists at all is to get around type erasure. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30007018/2398020

Comment: thanks a lot. I just wasting a lot of my time exploring the solution

Comment: @MingweiSamuel I think you're misunderstanding the question. The outer type is always `List`. Just inner type would be specified by `classType`.

Comment: @shmosel I'm thinking `Class<E> elementClass` as the argument to the method is going to suffer from type erasure while `TypeToken<E> elementToken` wouldn't, but I haven't actually tested the code

Comment: @MingweiSamuel No reason why that would be, considering you can easily construct a `TypeToken` from a `Class`.

Comment: Ah that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're looking for, this should do it:

```
static <E> TypeToken<List<E>> listToken(Class<E> elementClass) {
    return new TypeToken<List<E>>() {}
            .where(new TypeParameter<E>() {}, elementClass);
}
```

See [ReflectionExplained](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ReflectionExplained) for more info.

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'where(anonymous com.google.common.reflect.TypeParameter<E>, com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken<E>)'

Comment: That's a bad import. I assuming you're asking about Guava?

Comment: I fix the import. Please provide the demo to use the method

Comment: And what happened?

Comment: Required type:TypeToken<E>
Provided:Class<Application>

Comment: @tuhin47 My bad, fixed.

Comment: can't i pass the class reference and casting it inside the method

Comment: What's the problem now?

Comment: actually i can't use common typetoken as I have to work with gson. following problem occurs.
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken$SimpleTypeToken cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.Type

Comment: btw Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you call `getType()`?